# Facebook api: get users by work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get all Facebook users by work ID? I tried to find it via google but I'm getting the results I need.

I have the 'work ID' (which is infact a page, right?), but now I need all users that work there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to get all users by work directly from FB. You can query the user table to get a particular user's work history but the converse isn't possible. Perhaps LinkedIn offers that kind of data ? But Facebook doesn't AFAIK.

Comment: I'll have a look at the linkedin api, thanks for your comment!